# Using recursion check each pair in a list, if their sum is negative return True else return False

Tags: list, python-3.x, recursion

This is what I have so far.

```
def negative_sum(L):  
    if len(L) == 2:  
        if L[0] + L[1] <0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return negative_sum(L[0] + negative_sum(L[1:]))
```

My base case should be correct. My problem is with my final else statement. I need it to check the sum of each pair of the list. I'm having a lot of trouble trying to do this recursively. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Also I cannot use for loops.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/26308996/1193075.

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop is equivalent to 'tail recursion' withing a single execution frame.  Some problems are easier to express with recursion, others with loops.  Generating pairs is easily done with nested `for` loops.

```
def pairs1(seq``):
    n = len(seq)
    pairlist = []
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            pairlist.append((seq[i],seq[j]))
    return pairlist

inp = (1, 2, 3)
out = [(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)]
assert pairs1(inp) == out
```

I would usually use `yield` instead of `pairlist.append`.  Note the inclusion of a test with the code.  As an intermediate step, convert to a single `while` loop.

```
def pairs2(seq):
    jmax = len(seq) - 1
    pairlist = []
    i = 0
    j = i+1
    while i < jmax:
        pairlist.append((seq[i],seq[j]))
        if j < jmax:
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1
            j = i+1
    return pairlist

assert pairs2(inp) == out
```

Now it is not too hard to convert to using a nested tail recursive closure instead of the while statement.

```
def pairs3(seq):
    jmax = len(seq) - 1
    pairlist = []
    i = 0
    j = i+1
    def inner():
        nonlocal i, j
        if i < jmax:
            pairlist.append((seq[i],seq[j]))
            if j < jmax:
                j += 1
            else:
                i += 1
                j = i+1
            inner()
    inner()
    return pairlist

assert pairs3(inp) == out
```

Here is a more traditional form.

```
def pairs4(seq, i, j, pairlist):
    jmax = len(seq) - 1
    if i < jmax:
        pairlist.append((seq[i],seq[j]))
        if j < jmax:
            return pairs4(seq, i, j+1, pairlist)
        else:
            return pairs4(seq, i+1, i+2, pairlist)
    else:
        return pairlist

assert pairs4(inp, 0, 1, []) == out
```

A strict functionalist would replace pairlist with pairtuple, replace the initial [] with (), and replace the list.append mutation with tuple addition in the recursive calls.  The first call would look like this.

```
        return pairs4(seq, i, j+1, pairtuple + ((seq[i],seq[j])))
```

In Python, all the copying in the additions turns an O(N) function into an O(N**2) function, so I will not do it that way.