# Is there a way to write a recursive function that looks through all the integers in a list and sees if any two are equal to a negative sum?

Tags: python, recursion

So the problem is, you have a list of integers and you have to find if any two in the list sum to a negative.

right now I have this

```
def negsum(L):
    if len(L) <= 2:
        if L[0] + L[1] >= -1: #Here is my base case
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else: 
        if L[0] + L[1] <= -1:
            return True
        else:
            return negsum(L[1:]) #Recursive portion
```

The issue with my code is it only checks the first 2 in the list.  So in a list
[-10, 15, 30, -5] you get False when it should be true, because -5 + -10 is a negative sum.  My function only checks:

-10 + 15

15 + 30

30 - 5

How can I get it so that it checks -10 + 30, -10 -5 and 15-5 using recursion?

Edit, I forgot to mention, only len() [] and : operators are allowed.  No loops.  Is this even possible without loops?

Comment: Wouldn't you just sort them and check if the two least values sum to `<0`?

Comment: Or if algorithmic complexity is of utmost importance, `return sum(heapq.nsmallest(2,L)) < 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without loops (implicit or explicit):

```
def negsum(lst, sub=True):
    return len(lst) > 1 \
        and ((lst[0] + lst[1]) < 0
                or negsum([lst[0]]+lst[2:], False)
                or (sub and negsum(lst[1:])))
```

or, alternatively, the following version separates the process more cleanly into 2 sub-functions and doesn't need the additional parameter 'sub':

```
def negsum(lst):
    def first_with_others(lst): # compare lst[0] with all later values
        if len(lst) > 1:
            #print("summing", lst[0], "and", lst[1])
            return ((lst[0] + lst[1]) < 0) or first_with_others([lst[0]]+lst[2:])
    def drop_first(lst): # successively drop first element
        if lst:
            return first_with_others(lst) or drop_first(lst[1:])
    return drop_first(lst) or False # converts None to False
```

Uncommenting the call to the print function shows which sums are calculated:

```
>>> negsum([1,2,3,4,5])
summing 1 and 2
summing 1 and 3
summing 1 and 4
summing 1 and 5
summing 2 and 3
summing 2 and 4
summing 2 and 5
summing 3 and 4
summing 3 and 5
summing 4 and 5
False
>>> negsum([-1,2,3,4,5])
summing -1 and 2
summing -1 and 3
summing -1 and 4
summing -1 and 5
summing 2 and 3
summing 2 and 4
summing 2 and 5
summing 3 and 4
summing 3 and 5
summing 4 and 5
False
>>> negsum([-1,2,3,-4,5])
summing -1 and 2
summing -1 and 3
summing -1 and -4
True
>>> negsum([-2,1])
summing -2 and 1
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
def negsum(L):
    if len(L)<2: return False
    if len(L) == 2:
        if sum(L)<0: return True
        else: return False
    for i,elem in enumerate(L):
        if elem < 0:
            return negsum(L[i+1:]+[elem])
```

Output:

```
In [39]: negsum([1,2,3,4,5])
Out[39]: False

In [40]: negsum([-1,2,3,4,5])
Out[40]: False

In [41]: negsum([-1,2,3,-4,5])
Out[41]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to divide the list intwo parts: the first element `L[0]` and the rest `L[1:]` and apply the function recursively to the `L[1:]` part:

```
def negsum(L):
    if len(L) == 2:     # base case
        return True if L[0] + L[1] < 0 else False 
    elif negsum(L[1:]): # recursion on the L[1:] part
        return True
    else:               # check L[1:] part pairwise against the first element
        return any(x + L[0]<0 for x in L[1:])
```